# JS: How to prevent race condition?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

My task is to improve the performance on an existing WordPress site therefore I installed  cache and a race condition started happening.

This is [the site](https://seefar.org/). The full code is [here](https://pastebin.com/PCdGpJQQ), it doesn't fit in the editor, on line 474 there's this function

```
function loaded() {
    var e = $("#content-wrap").attr("data-classes");
    if ($("body").attr("class", e), $("#news-slider").length) {
        var t = $("#news-slider").attr("data-timer");
        $("#news-slider").slick({
            dots: !1,
            autoplay: !0,
            speed: 800,
            autoplaySpeed: t,
            fade: !0,
            cssEase: "linear",
            prevArrow: "<span class='prev-slide'><i class='fa fa-angle-left'></i></span>",
            nextArrow: "<span class='next-slide'><i class='fa fa-angle-right'></i></span>"
        })
    }

...
```

this line

`$("#news-slider").slick({`

gives `slick not defined`, sometimes, again it's a race condition. Sometimes an error in another function below it, the problem starts from `loaded()` function and below. Now I stopped caching the file and the homepage, where the file is loaded, the problem persists.

If I use `$(window).load(function()` either on the entire file or just this function, the homepage would be messed up, no errors would be visible in console though.

If I use `$(document).ready(function()` either on the entire file or just this function, the slider on mobile would be messed up, no errors would be visible in console though.

If I set a timer to delay the execution of the script, it wouldn't solve anything.

Comment: That `if()` doesn't make sense. You are setting the classes of body, not checking them and probably want an `||` for the length condition Also using `.load` as load event listener is deprecated. What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: @charlietfl I'm not the one who created the site, I was hired to fix it, unless the developer is using some version I don't know of, the jquery version is 2.2.4

Comment: Only pointing out what I see. The method deprecated in 1.8, removed in 3 https://api.jquery.com/load-event/.  Not sure what full intent of that `if()` is

Comment: @charlietfl, I removed the `if()`, I'll keep checking for 2 days, if the problem is solved, I'll ask you to answer this question so that I could accept it. It's a race condition so I have no faster way of verifying if the problem is solved.

Comment: Not sure why would be a race condition if scripts are all enqueued properly using `wp_enqueue_script`. My guess is they aren't

Comment: Looking at source seems home page loading 2 jquery versions

Comment: @charlietfl that's correct, there aren't, for instance slick isn't. jquery isn't. not sure how the previous developer loaded them. Will check jquery versions to see if  I could remove one.

Comment: @charlietfl the issue seems to be fixed, could you post an answer so that I could accept it please?